# Deprecation warning when using has_many :through :uniq in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 has introduced a deprecation warning when using :uniq => true with has_many :through. For example:

```
has_many :donors, :through => :donations, :uniq => true
```

Yields the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Goal.has_many :donors declaration are deprecated: :uniq. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

What is the correct way to rewrite the above has_many declaration?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

The `uniq` option needs to be moved into a scope block. Note that the scope block needs to be the second parameter to `has_many` (i.e. you can't leave it at the end of the line, it needs to be moved before the `:through => :donations` part):

```
has_many :donors, -> { uniq }, :through => :donations
```

It may look odd, but it makes a little more sense if you consider the case where you have multiple parameters. For example, this:

```
has_many :donors, :through => :donations, :uniq => true, :order => "name", :conditions => "age < 30"
```

becomes:

```
has_many :donors, -> { where("age < 30").order("name").uniq }, :through => :donations
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Where did you find this? I haven't been able to find it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: I actually saw it in the Upgrading to Rails 4 book (it's in progress): http://www.upgradingtorails4.com/ -- haven't been able to find it anywhere else.

Comment: @DylanMarkow the link for Upgrading to Rails 4 is defunct. The book has now been released under a CC license at https://github.com/alindeman/upgradingtorails4

Comment: With Rails 5 use `distinct` instead of `uniq`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578193/2116518) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Dylans answer, if you happen to be extending the association with a module, make sure that you chain it in the scope block (as opposed to specifying it separately), like so:

```
has_many :donors,
  -> { extending(DonorExtensions).order(:name).uniq },
  through: :donations
```

Maybe its just me but it seems very unintuitive to use a scope block to extend an association proxy.