# Using uniq in a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a unique constraint on a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship like so:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos, uniq: true
end
```

Because I only want unique `foos` when I call `user.foos`, I added the `uniq` option. Since upgrading to Rails 4 I've started to get the following warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your
>   User.has_and_belongs_to_many :foos declaration are deprecated: :uniq.
>   Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:
>
> ```
>   has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
> ```
>
> should be rewritten as the following:
>
> ```
>   has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
> ```

I've tried a number of different combinations, and read through the source, but can't figure out how to write the unique constraint to remove the warning?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569994/deprecation-warning-when-using-has-many-through-uniq-in-rails-4) could help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos, -> { uniq }
end
```

According to the [documentation here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: So, but if you use an `after_add` callback it will be repeated every time again

Comment: I know it's an old answer but commenting anyway. Thanks it works good and adds `DISTINCT` to the generated SQL. But the link you have shows no information for this.

Comment: and in rails 5.1 this won't work anymore and should be: `has_and_belongs_to_many : foos, -> { distinct }`

Comment: Oddly enough, this validation does not appear to preempt database-level constraints. That is, if you also set `add_index :join_table, [:user_id, :foo_id], unique: true` in the migration, and then you write a test/spec to see what happens when you try to add the same `foo` to a given `user` multiple times, the duplicate entry **won't be caught by the data model validation**, getting passed down to the database and raising an error. If anyone has any insight, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @RyanLue I believe that's because the uniq/distinct only impacts what's requested from the database, and not the behavior of the model that's being saved into it.  [discussion in this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129781/4096667)