# HABTM avoid dupe in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read this question : [has_and_belongs_to_many, avoiding dupes in the join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129781/has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table) but I wasn't able to fix my issue;

I've got a class `TypeProduit` which has many `ExtensionFichier` :

```
class TypeProduit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :extension_fichiers
end
```

and:

```
class ExtensionFichier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :type_produits
end
```

They are related thanks to

```
class LinkExtensionFichiers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_join_table :extension_fichiers, :type_produits
  end
end
```

## Edit:

Here's the [correct] Controler:

```
class TypeProduitsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_type_produit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /type_produits
# GET /type_produits.json
def index
  @type_produits = TypeProduit.all
end

# GET /type_produits/1
# GET /type_produits/1.json
def show
end

# GET /type_produits/new
def new
  @type_produit = TypeProduit.new
end

# GET /type_produits/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /type_produits
# POST /type_produits.json
def create
  @type_produit = TypeProduit.new(type_produit_params)

  puts "------extension_fichier_params------"
  puts extension_fichier_params

  #@type_produit.extension_fichier_ids = extension_fichier_params

  @type_produit.extension_fichiers << ExtensionFichier.find_by(:id => extension_fichier_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @type_produit.save
      format.html { redirect_to @type_produit, notice: 'Type produit was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @type_produit }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @type_produit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /type_produits/1
# PATCH/PUT /type_produits/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @type_produit.update(type_produit_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @type_produit, notice: 'Type produit was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @type_produit }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @type_produit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /type_produits/1
# DELETE /type_produits/1.json
def destroy
  @type_produit.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to type_produits_url, notice: 'Type produit was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_type_produit
    @type_produit = TypeProduit.find(params[:id])
  end

  def extension_fichier_params
    @type_produit.extension_fichier_ids
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def type_produit_params
    params.require(:type_produit).permit(:nom, :extension_fichier_ids => [])
  end
end
```

And here's the Rails server output:

```
Started POST "/type_produits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-27 17:55:15 +0100
Processing by TypeProduitsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4LBhwTvGjXOq+3qzO+loGUV/oBCYjW66aVDeE1Zj/AM=", "type_produit"=>{"nom"=>"qsdfqsdf", "extension_fichier_ids"=>["1", "2", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Type produit"}
  ExtensionFichier Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "extension_fichiers".* FROM "extension_fichiers"  WHERE "extension_fichiers"."id" IN (1, 2)
------extension_fichier_params------
1
2
  ExtensionFichier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "extension_fichiers".* FROM "extension_fichiers"  WHERE "extension_fichiers"."id" IN (1, 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  TypeProduit Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "type_produits"  WHERE "type_produits"."nom" = 'qsdfqsdf' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "type_produits" ("created_at", "nom", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-01-27 16:55:15.923132"], ["nom", "qsdfqsdf"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-27 16:55:15.923132"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "extension_fichiers_type_produits" ("extension_fichier_id", "type_produit_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["extension_fichier_id", 1], ["type_produit_id", 8]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "extension_fichiers_type_produits" ("extension_fichier_id", "type_produit_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["extension_fichier_id", 2], ["type_produit_id", 8]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "extension_fichiers_type_produits" ("extension_fichier_id", "type_produit_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["extension_fichier_id", 1], ["type_produit_id", 8]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
```

Why is rails making 3 insert while it just has 2 objects

Comment: You're showing the models and logs for the creation of a `TypeProduit` object, but your controller is the code for creating `Produit` objects. To diagnose this properly we need to see the `TypeProduitsController`

Comment: @smathy you're right, stupid copy/paste. It's fixed now

Comment: Your code looks right, you should check that there is no duplicate record for id 1 in your extension_fichiers table:

    `ExtensionFichier.find_by(:id => [1,2])`

That seems improbable though.

Comment: @ThomasGuillory no dupes in the DB :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very obvious error in your controller code. Let's go step by step through your `create` action.

You create a new `TypeProduit` from `type_produit_params` which includes `:nom` **and** `:extension_fichier_ids`. You then output the value of `extension_fichier_params` which itself is `@type_produit.extension_fichier_ids` and you get `"1\n2\n"` so your `@type_produit` already has both of those `extension_fichier`s attached to it.

You then append `ExtensionFichier.find_by(:id => extension_fichier_params)` to `@type_produit.extension_fichier_ids`. Now a `find_by` is basically a `where().first` so it gets only the first one, ie. id=1. So now in your `@type_produit.extension_fichiers` array you have ids 1, 2 and 1 again. Ie. three objects.

Then you save the `TypeProduit` and all three of those associations are saved with the three `INSERT`s.

And yeah, the overall solution to this (other than fixing your unnecessary `<<` code or your model-or-view that's adding 1 and 2) is to add the `-> { uniq }` scope to your habtm association(s) as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226630/152786

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution suggested by [using-uniq-in-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-relationship-in-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226525/using-uniq-in-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-relationship-in-rails-4) (and maybe also adding an index as suggested in [has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129781/has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table) ?)

Comment: The second link is the one I speak about in my question and the `uniq: true` doesn't work, but thanks !