# Rails 4 model associations conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a model that has polymorphic association with conditions.

This however doesn't seem to be working and it sounds like `conditions` are deprecated in Rails 4.

Below is my code for the association:

```
has_one :top_background, :class_name => 'UploadedFile', as: :imageable,
            :conditions => { :imageable_type => 'venue_top_background' }, dependent: :destroy
```

Is there a way to make this work in Rails 4?

Comment: This should be related to what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569994/deprecation-warning-when-using-has-many-through-uniq-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, conditions are achieved via a scope block as the second argument to has_one. For example:

```
has_one :top_background, ->{where(imageable_type: 'venue_top_background')}, :class_name => 'UploadedFile', as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
```