# Rails Upgraded syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I have this query

```
has_many :unused_invitations, :class_name => 'Invitation', :foreign_key => 'inviter_id', :conditions => 'used = false'
```

I was using rails 3.2.17 and now I am upgrading to rails 4.0.4. I got this error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your User.has_many :unused_invitations declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

I solve it by modifying query

```
has_many :used_invitations, class_name: 'Invitation', foreign_key: 'inviter_id', -> { where used: false}
```

But Still I getting syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)
```

What is wrong with query ? Will someone explain me about it. I have go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569994/deprecation-warning-when-using-has-many-through-uniq-in-rails-4) question but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solve this problem by updating the query

```
has_many :used_invitations, -> { where used: false}, class_name: 'Invitation', foreign_key: 'inviter_id'
```

Comment: Yes, the point is to declare finder options before the other ones.

Comment: @TaniaR Was racking my head on this for way too long thanks for the clarification.