# Conditions deprecated in rails use scope block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Product.has_many :recommended_users declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:
has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
should be rewritten as the following:
has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

I have tried to rewrite my code using the new scope block without much success:

```
has_many :current_products, :class_name => "Product", :through => :associations, :source => :product, :conditions => ["associations.category = ?", 1]
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569994/deprecation-warning-when-using-has-many-through-uniq-in-rails-4?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
has_many :current_products, -> { where "associations.category = ?", 1}, :class_name => "Product", :through => :associations, :source => :product
```

-OR-

```
has_many :current_products, -> { where "associations.category = 1"}, :class_name => "Product", :through => :associations, :source => :product
```

Refer **[API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)** for syntax and other details

You can also use `named_scope`. Refer to **[Named scope better than conditions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#761-Named-scope-better-than-conditions)**