# Remove deprecated `:distinct` option from `Relation#count` for Rails 4.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

Code:

```
checkin_scope.count(:select => "user_id", :distinct => true)
```

SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `checkins`.`user_id`) AS count_user_id, 
         location_id AS location_id 
FROM `checkins` INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.`id` = `checkins`.`location_id` 
WHERE `checkins`.`business_id` = 452 AND `checkins`.`status` = 'loyalty' 
    AND `locations`.`status` = 'approved' AND 
   `checkins`.`location_id` IN (302825, 302838, 302839, 302901) 
    AND (date(checkins.created_at) between '2014-10-11' and '2014-11-11') 
GROUP BY location_id
```

I need to remove :distinct => true as it has been removed in Rails 4.1.

Comment: what happens if you remove it now ? Just curious

Comment: @CaffeineCoder removing it doesn't give a distinct output.

Comment: Move the unique option into a scope block , read more on it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569994/deprecation-warning-when-using-has-many-through-uniq-in-rails-4

Comment: I guess you have read this that in Rails 4 they have Removed deprecated :distinct option from Relation#count. Have you tried using uniq where you have specified the relationship ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could solve the problem

```
checkin_scope.count("DISTINCT(checkins.user_id)")
```

where checkin_scope is a method,

```
def checkin_scope
  cscope = @business.checkins.loyalty_punchh.joins(:location).where(:locations => {:status => "approved"}).group(:location_id)
  cscope = cscope.for_location(@location) if @location
  if @from && @to
    cscope = cscope.where("date(checkins.created_at) between ? and ?",@from.to_date,@to.to_date)
  end
  cscope
end
```